# AggressiveInlining doesn't exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to implement OpenSimplex Noise https://gist.github.com/digitalshadow/134a3a02b67cecd72181 in my game, but I'm getting the error "'MethodImplOptions' does not contain a definition for 'AggressiveInlining'".

```
[ MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    private static int FastFloor(double x)
    {
        var xi = (int)x;
        return x < xi ? xi - 1 : xi;
    }
```

Yes, I included `using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;`. Now, I'll be perfectly honest, I don't know how inlining works, so I don't even know if it's necessary for a program in Unity. If I don't need it, I would like to know what to use instead. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

The `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining` enum does not exist because this feature was added in *.NET 4.5* while Unity is still using *.NET 2.0/3.5*.

> I don't even know if it's necessary for a program in Unity

It's not necessary but it seems to speed up function calling. You can see a speed test [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/aggressiveinlining).

> I would like to know what to use instead

You can use `[MethodImpl(256)]` instead of `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`. That should work too.

> [Why do you think it should work? I'm curious about that. Any sources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060376/aggressiveinlining-doesnt-exist#comment73211650_43060488)

Look at the source code for the [`MethodImplOptions`](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/7227962/) enum below:

```
public enum MethodImplOptions {
        Unmanaged = 4,
        ForwardRef = 16,
        InternalCall = 4096,
        Synchronized = 32,
        NoInlining = 8,
        PreserveSig = 128,
        NoOptimization = 64,
#if NET_4_5
        AggressiveInlining  = 256,
#endif
    } // MethodImplOptions
```

As you can see, `AggressiveInlining` has a value of `256`. When you use the [`MethodImplAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk6c2sk3(v=vs.110).aspx) construction overload with the `int` parameter, you can essentially use any `enum` value that does not exist. Passing it `256` should give you `AggressiveInlining` on any .NET version. The new enum value is simply there to make it easier to remember/use.

Another [source](https://twitter.com/xoofx/status/697025049916628996) is from Unity Engineer:

> Little .NET tip: use [MethodImpl(256)] instead of
>   MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining to compile on any .NET versions
>   and avoid ifdefs

Comment: Why do you think it should work? I'm curious about that. Any sources?

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: As Alexandre Mutel said, [MethodImpl(256)] helps to avoid ifdefs, but does it actually work for Unity .NET 2.0/3.5? (I mean JIT inlining). Are there some proofs/benchmarks? For example, Yoshifumi Kawai (author of the well known UniRx, ZeroFormatter and more) just ignores this attribute for Unity: https://github.com/neuecc/ZeroFormatter/blob/4274946b1b595b1c8bd395f7b368bbb674ec8029/src/ZeroFormatter/Internal/BinaryUtil.cs#L77

Comment: @gresolio I don't know. I haven't done the test but I think it should work fine. Note that Unity now supports .Net 4 so you can use that if this doesn't work for you.